# Recursive use of \renewcommand: How to make it work?

Tags: expansion, recursion

I am trying to define a command that is able to store the content of a section and accumulate it as new sections are created. My current attempt is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\storedContent}{}

\newcommand{\mySection}[1]{
    \section*{#1}
    \renewcommand{\storedContent}{#1}
}

\begin{document}
    \mySection{one}
    \mySection{\storedContent~two}
%    \mySection{\storedContent~three}
\end{document}
```

In practive, I would like it to display:

**one

one two

one two three**

However, it only works up to **one one two**. When `\mySection` is called the third time, LaTeX throws the error:

*TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]*

I suspect that this is caused by the fact that, when `\renewcommand{\storedContent}{#1}` is applied the second time, it operates recursively on itself. Probably, the argument of the `\renewcommand` must be expanded in order to first retrieve the content of the previous `\storedContent`, but I just can't figure out how to do it...

Comment: Use `\csname protected@edef\endcsname\storedContent` instead of `\renewcommand{\storedContent}`. `\protected@edef` is the LaTeX version of `\edef` which, as you say, expands the argument first.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add the item *before* doing `\section`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\storedContent}{}
\newcommand{\mySection}[1]{%
  \ifdefempty{\storedContent}
    {\gappto\storedContent{#1}}
    {\gappto\storedContent{~#1}}%
  \section*{\storedContent}
}

\begin{document}

\mySection{one}

\mySection{two}

\mySection{three}

\end{document}
```

Using `etoolbox` is just for convenience; the same could be done without packages.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this perfectly fits my needs! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 10):

One way would be this (there are others). The comma is only there to show you, how you can do something different with the second, third occurance than with the first.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\storedContent}{}
\makeatletter
\let\storedContent\@empty
\newcommand{\mySection}[1]{%
    \section*{#1}
    \ifx\storedContent\@empty
     \g@addto@macro\storedContent{#1}%
    \else
     \g@addto@macro\storedContent{, #1}%
    \fi 
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
    \mySection{one}
    \mySection{two}
    \mySection{three}
\storedContent    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Very nice workarround to my problem, while avoiding a more troublesome recursive solution. Thanks!