# Create a macro to append elements to another macro

Tags: macros, renewcommand

##### General overview

The goal is to make a list of photo credits at the end of a book.

##### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\credittable{} % This command contain the final rendering. 

\newcommand{\addcredit}[1] % Prepare each entry rendering for \credittable and append it.
{
  \let\tempcredittable\credittable
  \renewcommand{\credittable}{\expandafter\tempcredittable #1. }
}

\begin{document}


\addcredit{Author0} 
\addcredit{Author1}

{\Large Credits}
\credittable % Make the final list of credits
\end{document}
```

##### The problem

This is the output of `xelatex`:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\tempcredittable ->\expandafter \tempcredittable A
                                                  uthor0.
l.20 \credittable

No pages of output.
Transcript written on test.log.
```

But, I noticed this code works when their is only one entry. Witch isn’t helpful.

##### The question

So, how to create a command who append another existing command?

Comment: Do you want to process each element of the final list, or just set them in the text as-is?

Comment: Related: [Recursive use of `\renewcommand`: How to make it work?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/281514/5764)

Comment: For the benefit of others, who find this question for more general purposes than the specific question asked: The `etoolbox` package has `\apptocmd` and `\pretocmd` macros. See its documentation. Particularly note that the macros have extra mandatory arguments (which you may leave empty) that can trap whether the macro succeeded or failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find this sollution with etoolbox:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand\credittable{} % This command contain the final rendering. 

\newcommand{\addcredit}[1]{ % Append the new content to \credittable
  \gappto\credittable{#1. }
}

\begin{document}

\addcredit{Author0} 
\addcredit{Author1}

{\Large Credits}
\credittable % Make the final list of credits
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are the additional spaces deliberate?

Answer (score 3):

You need to do the one-level expansion at definition time:

```
\newcommand{\addcredit}[1]
{% <--- don't forget
  \expandafter\gdef\expandafter\credittable\expandafter{\credittable #1. }% <--- don't forget
}
```

In this case `\def` is simpler to use; better yet, `\gdef` so grouping will not affect the redefinition.

There are better ways.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for the last example

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\addcredit}{m}
 {
  \fauve_credit_add:n { #1 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\credittable}{sO{.~}}
 {
  \fauve_credit_print:n { #2 }
  \IfBooleanF{#1}{#2}
 }

\seq_new:N \g_fauve_credit_list_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \fauve_credit_add:n
 {
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_fauve_credit_list_seq { #1 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \fauve_credit_print:n
 {
  \seq_use:Nn \g_fauve_credit_list_seq { #1 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}


\addcredit{A.~Uthor (London)} 
\addcredit{R.~Eporter (New York)}

\section*{Credits}

\credittable

\section*{Credits again}

\credittable*[ -- ]

\section*{Credits in table}

\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{}}{Credits} \\
\midrule
\credittable[\\]
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

With `\credittable*` the separator is not repeated at the end. The default value of the separator is “period space”.

Quite flexible, isn't it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want? :

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\credittable{}%

\newcommand{\addcredit}[1]{%
  \expandafter\renewcommand
  \expandafter{%
  \expandafter\credittable
  \expandafter}%
  \expandafter{%
  \credittable
  \formatcreditentry{#1}}%
}

\newcommand\formatcreditentry[1]{#1. }%

\begin{document}

\addcredit{Author0} 
\addcredit{Author1}

{\Large Credits}
\credittable % Make the final list of credits
\end{document}
```

You might be interestred in

- how `\expandafter` actually works,
- `\g@addto@macro`,
- the `\@starttoc`-`\addtocontents`-mechanism of the LaTeX 2ε-kernel.